# How do type synonyms work with multi functions?

Tags: haskell, types

I saw that you can create type synonyms with functions that project multiple times, but I don't quite understand how this is supposed to be used.

Here is an example I just made up, which I guess would show such an usecase, but I am not able to define the function `throwParty`. How would I go about using such a type synonym?

**My example**

```
type DamagedFurniture = String
type Person           = String
type Friend           = Person
type Acquaintances    = Person -> Friend -> [Person]

throwParty :: Person -> Acquaintances -> DamagedFurniture
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s equivalent to

```
throwParty :: Person -> (Person -> Friend -> [Person]) -> DamagedFurniture
```

and not

```
throwParty :: Person -> Person -> Friend -> [Person] -> DamagedFurniture
```

Something you can do instead is:

```
type AcquaintancesTo a = Person -> Friend -> [Person] -> a

throwParty :: Person -> AcquaintancesTo DamagedFurniture
```

Comment: I see... but how would the definition of `throwParty` look like if I don't change the type synonym? I have trouble understanding how to represent the Acquaintances function. Something like: `throwParty host (host' friend [people]) = "broken door"` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what I thought, but now it is clear. You just pass the function which you can use inside...  `throwParty host calcPartyGuests = .... calcPartyGuests host someFriend ...`

Comment: @TomTom: It could look as if you hadn’t changed the definition at all, too: `throwParty host host' friend people = …`. If you want to represent `Acquaintances` as one entity, you should probably make it a data type: `data Acquaintances = Acquaintances Person Friend [Person]` Then `throwParty host (Acquaintances host' friend people) = …`